# Check whether an HttpServletRequest's connection is still open?

Tags: java, servlets, connection, jetty, httprequest

Using a synthetic load with both the client and the server running on localhost, I verified via tcpdump and netstat that the client is sending a FIN packet to the server, but the the connection is stuck in CLOSE_WAIT while the request remains queued on the server (I'm using Jetty with a queued thread pool). When a worker thread is available in the pool, the request is processed as usual by the servlet even though the connection has already been closed by the client.

What I want is a way to test whether the connection has already been closed to prevent the server from processing requests that have already timed out on the client side (I know I can set an http header on the client with a timestamp and check this on the server as long as the clocks are in sync, but I'd prefer to check the connection to see if it is still open as well).

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. FIN does not mean the connection is broken. It is perfectly valid that A sends B some data, followed by FIN; then A continues to read from B. Nothing wrong with this half-closed state.

Your better choice is to improve server throughput so that clients don't have to wait so long.

Comment: So you are suggesting if I want the client to timeout, and want to skip the work on the server once the client has timed out, the best solution is to put a timestamp in the header (other than improving server responsiveness of course)?

Comment: Yes, if you control the client behavior, that'll be a good solution.

Comment: However, since clocks can be out-of-sync, it's better that the server timestamps the request when it is received. I'm not familiar with jetty and don't know how to do that.